# How to inject Repo to utility class? Autowired not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, crud

I need some help to find solution for my problem. I created 1 utility class and inject here some CrudRepositories. But repositoryies doesn't works fine here. They returns NullPointerException (Repositories works fine only in controllers).
Here is error and some code.
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ImVU.png)

Once again, I note that such errors do not appear in the controller.

```
@Repository
public interface EventRepository extends CrudRepository<Event, Long> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select * from events e order by e.id desc LIMIT 5")
    List<Event> getEventsWithLimit();

}
```

```
@Service
public class CachedObject extends TimerTask {

    @Autowired
    EventRepository eventRepository;
    @Autowired
    MatchRepository matchRepository;
    @Autowired
    PlayerRepository playerRepository;
    @Autowired
    ImageRepository imageRepository;

    List<Rank> ranking;

    List<Image> image;

    //Last 10 next Matches
    List<Match> nextMatches;

    //Last 10 results
    List<Match> results;

    List<PlayerOfTheWeek> playerOfTheWeek;

    //Last 5 event
    List<Event> events;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            refreshCache();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void refreshCache() throws Exception{

        events = eventRepository.getEventsWithLimit();
        image = imageRepository.getRandomImage();
        results = matchRepository.getLastResult();
        nextMatches = matchRepository.getLastMatches();
        ranking = makeRanking();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Can you give me some tips for find solution guys?((

Comment: Show the code where you using the service.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use solution TimerTask i think u need  to create a constructor with needed autowired beans. But better solution in spring is to use @Scheduler annotation to periodically execute needed method. (more about Schedulers in spring https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)

Comment: OMG!!! That is working. I changed TimerTask to @Scheduler as you said. Thanks a lot!